# Rails scope limit before where

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to be able limit my results before I preform a where query. I'm trying to do an experiment where I look at a random sample of say 50 responses and then want to count the number of users that responded yes. If I do `response.limit(50).where(:chosen_answer => 'yes').count` I get 50 since it preforms the limit on the whole query.

Is there a way to make this into two separate queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as a single query but by using a nested query:

```
# get 50
inner_query = response.select('id').limit(50).to_sql

# then filter within those 50
results = response.joins("INNER JOIN #{inner_query} x on x.id = responses.id").where(...).count
```

Comment: No I don't want 50 results. I want to take a set of results (Chosen by some other metric) limit them 50 and then count how many of those 50 match a criteria.