# Rails - want to apply limit before where

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I first have this:

```
@shots = @team.shots.order_by_recent.limit(5)
```

I then want to use `@shots` in other methods:

```
made = @shots.where(made: true).count
=> 5 (should be 2)

missed = @shots.where(made: true).count
=> 5 (should be 3)
```

Generated query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT count_column) 
FROM (SELECT  "shots"."id" AS count_column FROM "shots" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "games" ON "games"."id" = "shots"."game_id" 
WHERE "shots"."team_id" = $1 AND "shots"."shot_area" = $2 
AND "shots"."shot_range" = $3 AND "shots"."made" = 'f' LIMIT 5) 
subquery_for_count  [["team_id", 3], ["shot_area", "Left Side Center(LC)"], ["shot_range", "24+ ft."]]
```

I notice that the `LIMIT` is applied to the entire query at the end. What I want to do is apply the limit to the `@team.shots.order_by_recent` first, and then make additional queries on that.

Put another way:
I want to separate the query into two separate queries. The first query gets 5 records: @team.shots.order_by_recent.limit(5) and the second query selects from the first query. Right now, it seems Rails is automatically combining these two queries into one.

Comment: LIMIT goes after WHERE. That's the SQL syntax. There's nowhere else that it could be with your example query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532852/sql-limit-with-where-clause (what am I missing?)

Comment: I guess what I mean is that I want to separate the query into two separate queries. The first query gets 5 records: `@team.shots.order_by_recent.limit(5)` and the second query selects from the first query. Right now, it seems Rails is automatically combining these two queries into one.

Comment: Oh you want something like the 5 "most recent" and then you want to query against those 5 most recent records ?

Comment: @mmcrae Exactly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488506/rails-scope-limit-before-where is very similar to my question, but I wonder if there is a "Rails way" of doing it without relying on explicit SQL.

Comment: Couldn't you call .count or some similar method that forces the query to actually execute? TBH I'm not familiar with Rails, but that's one way to go about it -- do something to get the query to execute with your Order By and Limit, and then filter it.

Comment: @mmcrae Even when I do:     `shots = Shot.limit(5).load
    puts shots.all.count
    puts shots.where(made: true).count
    puts shots.where(made: false).count`

The LIMIT is applied to the latter two queries: `SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "shots" WHERE "shots"."made" = 't' LIMIT 5)` ... etc.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with rails' database querying functions. But there *must* be some way to tell rails to execute a query, and return results from the DB, and give you a list of those results. Then when you know you've only queried the five latest and they're in-memory, filter the list